# split wordpress loop into columns of categories and associated posts

Tags: pagination, columns, loop

Here is what I need to do with 5 columns on the "archive" page:

I can already loop through the categories and posts in a loop to display them quite nicely, I just cant figure out how to split it into columns.  I also need it to be paged.  Basically show only 18 post titles/excerpts per page.  Any help?  My loop below:

**UPDATE: I am posted the working solution below.  This works perfectly to break a continuous loop of posts sorted and displayed by category of any type or taxonomy.**

**WHAT STILL NEEDS WORK:** I cannot seem to figure out how to make the paging work.  I need the paging to count total posts (ignoring the categories) and display only 12 or so per page.  I have added the paging code but it is commented out.

```
<?php
// for a given post type, return all
        $post_type = 'retailers';
        $tax = 'states';
        $tax_terms = get_terms($tax);
        $post_counter = 0; // reset so we can generate columns 
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            if ($tax_terms) { ?>

            <ul class="column_wrap" style="margin:0 10px; padding:0; width:165px; float:left;">

            <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
                 $args=array(
                'post_type' => $post_type,
                "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
              //'posts_per_page' => 15,
              //'paged' => $paged,
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'caller_get_posts'=> 1
                ); // END $args

                $my_query = null; // clear the query variable
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

                      <li class="column_row" style="float:left;">

                        <div class="retailer_state_wrap" style="width:165px; float:left;">
                            <h4><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></h4>
                        </div>

                      </li>

        <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                      <li class="column_row" style="float:left;">

                          <div class="retailer_wrap retailer_id-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="padding:0; width:165px; float:left;">
                            <p>
                              <span class="retailer_title"><?php the_title(); ?></span><br />
                              <span class="retailer_address">
                                <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_2_numInSet_0', true)) { ?>
                                  <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_2_numInSet_0', true); ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php echo " "; ?>
                                <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_1_numInSet_0', true)) { ?>
                                  <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_1_numInSet_0', true); ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                              </span><br />
                              <span class="retailer_phone">                               
                                <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_2_fieldID_3_numInSet_0', true)) {
                                  echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_2_fieldID_3_numInSet_0', true); ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                              </span>    
                            </p>                                          
                          </div>
                          <?php $post_counter++; ?>
                        </li>

                        <?php if ( 0 == $post_counter % 7 ) { ?>
                          </ul>
                          <ul class="column_wrap" style="margin:0 10px; padding:0; width:165px; float:left;">
                        <?php } ?>
                      <?php
                      endwhile;
                      //wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) ); 
                    } // END if have_posts loop
                    wp_reset_query();

                  } // END foreach $tax_terms
                } // END if $tax_terms
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is loop through an array of category IDs. For example:

```
$categories = get_categories();
```

Then loop through the categories, and use the category id in your query_posts:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args = array(
    'cat' = $category->ID
    )
    // return your loop here...
}
```

Or something... assuming I understand your question.

Comment: Well I can already display 1 long list of categories with posts using my query.  I just need to know how to divide that long list into 5 columns and then make it paged. Here is the manual HTML version http://bottlesup-07112011.31two.com/bottlesup-retailers/ to give you an idea.

Comment: OK, that wasn't too clear in your question.

Have a look at the offset parameter for query_posts. Or, show say 25 posts per page, and add closing and opening div after every 5 to split it.

Comment: So I guess I will edit my post to make the nested loop much more clear. Please review.